# How do you set the main program in xcode when using pascal?

Tags: xcode, macos, pascal

I am getting the following error using xcode with pascal:

```
warning: It seems your project only contains units and no main program
```

What causes this warning?  And how do I set the main program?

I am using: `Xcode 4.5.2`, `Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0`, and `Mac OSX 10.8`.

Comment: By the way, I am using free pascal compiler...

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.5.2, Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0, and Mac OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're missing the `.dpr` (project file) that tells the compiler what type of project it should be building. The project file for Delphi (and the Borland Pascal and Turbo Pascal compilers before it) typically look something like:

```
{ For a GUI (Windows) application }
program MyProgram;

uses
  Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {fMain};

{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  Application.Run;
end.

{ For a console application }
program MyProgram;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE }    

uses
  MyMain, SysUtils;

begin
  try
    { 
       Execute your application's entry point (main()) here, in this case
       contained in MyMain.pas that's listed in the uses clause above.
    }
  except
    { Handle any exception here }
  end;
end.
```

In Delphi XE2, you then run `dpr2xcode.exe` to create a corresponding Xcode project. (I don't know what the corresponding step would be in FreePascal, but you might look for something like that in your FP install.)  Open that `.xcodeproj` file in `Xcode` on the Mac, and then run or debug the code.

For specific info on using FreePascal and Xcode, I recommend a [series of articles](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/ObjP_Info.html) by Phil Hess.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Where do I place the file in the Xcode directory structure and notify XCode to run the file when building the project?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, I'm afraid. AFAIK, you just use your other units in this one, and then use the project file as your main file for FreePascal. I haven't done any Xcode work with it myself, though. I use Delphi XE2 for OSX dev, which doesn't use Xcode, and haven't done any iOS work (which does).

Comment: The problem is that Delphi costs $$$ and Xcode comes with the Mac OSX.  Thus, my reason to use XCode.

Comment: I know. ;-) Hang on; I'm finding a link to add to my question to detailed instructions on compiling iOS/OSX code with FreePascal.

Comment: Actually, FPC has $apptype console as default. Moreover, in FPC the program line is not mandatory (TP legacy) for a main program, and forms is a Lazarus unit (and thus probably has no place in a XCode project). Forms and above is pretty much the definition of Lazarus :-) Since XCode is not a native Pascal IDE, it might need some special parameter to its project that signals which module is the main one